# Issues Scraping multiple webpages with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a URL (example: https://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-dogecoin-addresses-4.html) and the number on the end of the URL is the page number. I am trying to scrape multiple pages, so I used the following code to loop through the multiple pages:

```
for page in range(4, 7): #Range designates the page numbers for the URL
        r = s.get(f'https://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-dogecoin-addresses-{page}.html') #Format the page number into url
        print(page)
```

When I run the code in my script and print the page, it returns 4, 5 and 6, meaning that it should be working. However whenever I run the full code, it only gives me the results for the 6th page.

What I think may be happening is the code is finalizing on the last number and formatting that into the URL, whenever it should formatting each number into the URL instead.

I have tried looking at other people with similar issues but haven't been able to find a solution. I believe this may be a code formatting error but I am not exactly sure. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the remainder of my code:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from datetime import datetime
import os
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

# define 1-1-2020 as a datetime object
after_date = datetime(2021, 1, 1)

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {"User-Agent": "Safari/537.36"}
    for page in range(4, 7): #Range designates the page numbers for the URL
        r = s.get(f'https://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-dogecoin-addresses-{page}.html') #Format the page number into url
        print(page)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

        # select all tr elements (minus the first one, which is the header)
        table_elements = soup.select('tr')[1:]
        address_links = []
    for element in table_elements:
        children = element.contents  # get children of table element
        url = children[1].a['href']
        last_out_str = children[8].text
        if last_out_str != "": # check to make sure the date field isn't empty
            last_out = datetime.strptime(last_out_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z") # load date into datetime object for comparison
            if last_out > after_date: # if check to see if the date is after last_out
                address_links.append(url + '-full') #add adddress_links to the list, -full makes the link show all data
                print(address_links)

    for url in address_links: #loop through the urls in address_links list

        r = s.get(url)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')


        ad2 = (soup.title.string) #grab the web title which is used for the filename
        ad2 = ad2.replace('Dogecoin', '')
        ad2 = ad2.replace('Address', '')
        ad2 = ad2.replace('-', '')
        filename = ad2.replace(' ', '')

        sections = soup.find_all(class_='table-striped')

        for section in sections: #This contains the data which is imported into the 'gf' dataframe or the 'info' xlsx sheet



            oldprofit = section.find_all('td')[11].text #Get the profit
            removetext = oldprofit.replace('USD', '')
            removetext = removetext.replace(' ', '')
            removetext = removetext.replace(',', '')
            profit = float(removetext)


            balance = section.find_all('td')[0].text #Get the wallet balance 

            amount_recieved = section.find_all('td')[3].text #Get amount recieved 

            ins = amount_recieved[amount_recieved.find('(') + 1:amount_recieved.find(')')] #Filter out text from 
            # amount recieved
            ins = ins.replace('ins', '')
            ins = ins.replace(' ', '')
            ins = float(ins)

            first_recieved = section.find_all('td')[4].text #Get the data of the first incoming transaction

            fr = first_recieved.replace('first', '')
            fr = fr.replace(':', '')
            fr = fr.replace(' ', '')

            last_recieved = section.find_all('td')[5].text #Get the date of the last incoming transaction 

            lr = last_recieved.replace('last', '')
            lr = lr.replace(':', '')
            lr = lr.replace(' ', '')

            amount_sent = section.find_all('td')[7].text #Get the amount sent 

            outs = amount_sent[amount_sent.find('(') + 1:amount_sent.find(')')] #Filter out the text
            outs = outs.replace('outs', '')
            outs = outs.replace(' ', '')
            outs = float(outs)

            first_sent = section.find_all('td')[8].text #Get the first outgoing transaction date

            fs = first_sent.replace('first', '') #clean up first outgoing transaction date 
            fs = fs.replace(':', '')
            fs = fs.replace(' ', '')

            last_sent = section.find_all('td')[9].text #Get the last outgoing transaction date

            ls = last_sent.replace('last', '') #Clean up last outgoing transaction date
            ls = ls.replace(':', '')
            ls = ls.replace(' ', '')

            dbalance = section.find_all('td')[0].select('b') #get the balance of doge 
            dusd = section.find_all('td')[0].select('span')[1] #get balance of USD

            for data in dbalance: #used to clean the text up 
                balance = data.text

            for data1 in dusd: #used to clean the text up 
                usd = data1.text

            # Compare profit to goal, if profit doesn't meet the goal, the URL is not scraped 

            goal = float(30000)

            if profit < goal:
                continue
                
            #Select wallets with under 2000 transactions 
                
            trans = float(ins + outs) #adds the amount of incoming and outgoing transactions 

            trans_limit = float(2000)

            if trans > trans_limit:
                continue

            # Create Info Dataframe using the data from above 

            info = {
                'Balance': [balance],
                'USD Value': [usd],
                'Wallet Profit': [profit],

                'Amount Recieved': [amount_recieved],
                'First Recieved': [fr],
                'Last Recieved': [lr],

                'Amount Sent': [amount_sent],
                'First Sent': [fs],
                'Last Sent': [ls],
                }

            gf = pd.DataFrame(info)
            a = 'a'

            if a:
                df = \
                pd.read_html(requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).text, attrs={"id": "table_maina"},
                            index_col=None, header=[0])[0] #uses pandas to read the dataframe and save it 

                directory = '/Users/chris/Desktop/Files' #directory for the file to go to 

                file = f'{filename}.xlsx'

                writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(directory, file), engine='xlsxwriter')

                with pd.ExcelWriter(writer) as writer:
                    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='transactions')
                    gf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='info')
```

Comment: Try printing the url instead of using request if you need to check the problem

Answer (score 0):

Check your indentation - In your question the loops are on the same level, so loop that make the requests is iterating over all the pages but results are never processed until iterating is done. That is why it only works for the last page.

Move your loops, that should handle the response and extract elements into your first loop:

```
...
for page in range(4, 7): #Range designates the page numbers for the URL
    r = s.get(f'https://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-dogecoin-addresses-{page}.html') #Format the page number into url
    print(page)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

    table_elements = soup.select('tr')[1:]
    address_links = []

    for element in table_elements:
        ...
    for url in address_links:
        ...
```